# Zend Framework $_REQUEST equivalent

Tags: php, zend-framework

I need to capture several parameters in a controller regardless of whether the were posted or they are in the url.

Does **$this->_request->getParam('parameter')** work regardless?

Comment: I'm just curious. Why is it that you don't know before hand how your variables will be passed? Surley you know which method your forms submit with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make life easier and shorter code, you can use the `_getParam` function in your controllers:

```
$page = $this->_getParam('page', 1);
```

Note that the second function variable is the default value if the request didn't include that specific variable.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, yes.

If you are in the controller, you can access any POST of GET parameter by accessing the getParam() method like you said.

`$this->getRequest()->getParam("foo")` will get the parameter `foo`, if it is present in the URL via a get param, or in a POST. It will also get any user set parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

Will get several parameters regardless of the action type being sent (get or post).

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('foo');
```

Will get you individual requested parameter.

Answer (score 0):

i prefer always use short function:

```
$parameter = $this->_getParam('parameter');
```